# Pandas grouby indexing : discard entire group if condition is not met

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'alpha':['a','a','b','b'],'beta':[1,2,3,4]})
```

[image]

The idea is to only return groups where certain condition is met on column `beta`, otherwise discard the entire group

The outcome I want is:

[image]

However, something like for eg.

```
df.groupby('alpha').apply(lambda x: x.beta>1)
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try not using `groupby` , `isin`

```
df.loc[~df.alpha.isin(df.loc[df.beta<=1,'alpha'])]
Out[316]: 
  alpha  beta
2     b     3
3     b     4
```

If do want groupby , you can using `transform` , since this is more efficient than pass `lambda`

```
df[df.beta.gt(1).groupby(df.alpha).transform('all')]
Out[317]: 
  alpha  beta
2     b     3
3     b     4
```

---

Timing

```
%timeit df.groupby('alpha').filter(lambda x: (x.beta >1).all())
100 loops, best of 3: 2.53 ms per loop
%timeit df.loc[~df.alpha.isin(df.loc[df.beta<=1,'alpha'])]
1000 loops, best of 3: 874 µs per loop
%timeit df[df.beta.gt(1).groupby(df.alpha).transform('all')]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.04 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`groupby.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) such as:

```
print (df.groupby('alpha').filter(lambda x: (x.beta >1).all()))
  alpha  beta
2     b     3
3     b     4
```

For the `lambda`, I understood that you want that `all` the value of the group in `beta` should be over 1 according to your expected output.